# Deploy socks5 proxy on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, port, heroku-connect

I decided to run socks5 proxy server on heroku. Found simle example on github (https://github.com/Kecon/JSocksProxy), build jar, deploy to heroku, then launched.
but I can not use it since the port (8090) that I defined is closed. Is it possible to open ports in a heroku? Is it a good idea to use herotu as a free proxy server? I will need it for 2 hours a day.